# How do I use RegEx to replace this text with a more complicated line?

Tags: regex

I have the following in my T-SQL code within SSMS:

```
select

    t.*
    , coalesce(e.[1], 0) Week1_Expiring
    , coalesce(e.[2], 0) Week2_Expiring
    , coalesce(e.[3], 0) Week3_Expiring
    , coalesce(e.[4], 0) Week4_Expiring
    , coalesce(e.[5], 0) Week5_Expiring
     ....
```

I need to replace each of the lines that start with `coalesce(...` with the following:

```
, case when coalesce(e.[1], 0) = 0 then '' else 'Qty Expiring: ' + cast(coalesce(e.[1], 0) as nvarchar(30)) Week1_Expiring
```

...where each line will have the correct number in `e.[NUMBER]` and in `WeekNUMBER_Expiring`.

How do I accomplish this?

If I type in `e.[[]` into the Find field, it highlights `e.[` for all lines. If I do `e.[[0-9]`, it highlights the `ek2` in `Week2_Expiring`, but for all lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just regex the coalesce pattern which seems consistent and simple per your example:

```
coalesce\(e\.\[\d+\], \d+\)
```

And use `$0` in your replacement string.

You can put your entire SQL into the "Test String" field of regex101 and copy the "Substitution" section back into your T-SQL.

https://regex101.com/r/0nVgPb/1/

Comment: @whatwhatwhat Nice, I'm glad your data had no surprises